# Dynamic Scroll Position in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please help me for below scenario

i have 3 pages in place and user scrolls the page when scroll reach the second page, it has to find the specific ID and then trigger a function. once the third page starts another function triggers. 
As per the requirement i should not use any plugins

```
<script>
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var offset = $("#two").offset();
        var posY = offset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
        if (offset.top + $("#two").height() > $(window).scrollTop()) {
            apply();
        } else {
            remove();
        }
</script>
<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great plugin to do this called **[WAYPOINT](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints)**

I have setup an example on **[jsfiddle check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/mGtbK/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.first {
    background:green;
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
}
.second {
    background:red;
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.second').waypoint(function() {
    alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
}, {
    offset: '100%'
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. As per the requirement i should not use any plugins. Do u have any other idea