# Run javascript function when user scrolls to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a different function I want to run each time a user scrolls to another div or to another section of the page.  Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: Are those section located below each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allready Answered here -->> [Dynamic Scroll Position in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357239/dynamic-scroll-position-in-jquery/18358221#18358221)

There is a great plugin to do this called **[WAYPOINT](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints)**

I have setup an example on **[jsfiddle check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/mGtbK/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.first {
    background:green;
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
}
.second {
    background:red;
    height: 600px;
    width:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.second').waypoint(function() {
    alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
}, {
    offset: '100%'
});
```

Comment: hmm I'm trying waypoint but when I scroll to the div the function does not run

Comment: Mine is not also working.... :( What did you do to make it work @kduan

Answer (score 2):

There're many ways to do this. The most simplest method:

```
var element = $('#my-div');

function myFunction() {
    alert('I am here!');
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    if ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)) {
        myFunction();
    }
});
```

Also there're [jQuery Appear plugin](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) and [Waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/):

```
$('#my-div').appear(function() {
    alert('I am here!');
});

$('#my-div').waypoint(function() {
    alert('I am here!');
});
```