# GTM Trigger a Tag when a visitor views a section of your site (such as the footer)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

Is there a way to have GTM Trigger a Tag when a visitor views a section of your site (such as the footer)?

**Example**: Visitor comes to blog page, reads half way down (event triggered), then reads all the way down (another event triggered).

**Reason**: GA logs a bounce and zero session duration if there are no further interactions on the page. This makes it impossible to tell if a viewer read the blog, or left immediately.

I need a way to trigger an interaction once the viewer scrolls to a section, or get GTM to trigger an event.

Comment: Just create custom HTML tag with JS function which base on scroll addeventlistener. Check in that function does footer div is visible on screen and fire google analytics event. GTM doesn't have any built-in mechanism to check page scroll etc. (exception is GTM for AMP page :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one --> [Dynamic Scroll Position in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357239/dynamic-scroll-position-in-jquery/18358221#18358221)

But instead of an alert, do a

```
window.dataLayer.push({ 
    "event" : "scrollEvent",
    "eventLabel" : "Scrolled down the page"                            
});
```

Or if you prefer to use pixels instead of css class, try this other one: [Trigger events when the window is scrolled to certain positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672320/trigger-events-when-the-window-is-scrolled-to-certain-positions)

Comment: Thank you! The script works. I just now have to work out getting it into GTM.